# Choosing the largest Quantity for specific date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is the table

[image]

For each `(shopID, productID)` combination, I want to choose the maximum `Quantity`, and if they are multiple, just choose one randomly, result as follows:

[image]

The code for first table

```
from datetime import date 
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"Date":[date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,2),date(2019,10,2),date(2019,10,2),date(2019,10,3),date(2019,10,3),date(2019,10,3)],
                "ShopID":[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                "ProductID":[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1],
                "Quantity":[3,3,2,4,5,6,4,5,6],
                "Desc":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]})
```

How do I come up with second table?

Comment: groupby() will get you started. see e.g. https://wellsr.com/python/python-group-data-with-pandas-groupby/

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) 
to order based on `Quantity`.Then use [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) with **`ascending = False`** or [`groupby.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
new_df=df.sort_values('Quantity').groupby(['Date','ShopID','ProductID']).last()
print(new_df)
```

---

```
Date       ShopID ProductID  Quantity Desc             
2019-10-01 1      1                 3    b
2019-10-02 1      2                 6    f
2019-10-03 2      1                 6    i
```

or:

```
df.sort_values('Quantity',ascending=False).groupby(['Date','ShopID','ProductID']).first()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using groupby and idxmax function like below. It is efficient than sorting column

```py
from datetime import date 
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"Date":[date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,2),date(2019,10,2),date(2019,10,2),date(2019,10,3),date(2019,10,3),date(2019,10,3)],
                "ShopID":[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                "ProductID":[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1],
                "Quantity":[3,3,2,4,5,6,4,5,6],
                "Desc":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]})

ids = df.groupby(["ShopID", "ProductID", "Date"])["Quantity"].idxmax()
df.loc[ids]
```

Answer (score 2):

Both answers posted are wrong, since they work for this example, but don't keep into account that a `ShopID + ProductID` can be repeated for different days, and then their methods would fail. Here's a method which keeps `dt` as a group indicator as well:

```
df.sort_values(['ShopID', 'ProductID', 'dt', 'Quantity'], 
               ascending=[True, True, True, False]).groupby(['ShopID', 'ProductID', 'dt']).head(1)
```

**Output**

```
          dt  ShopID  ProductID  Quantity Desc
0 2019-10-01       1          1         3    a
5 2019-10-02       1          2         6    f
8 2019-10-03       2          1         6    i
```

Comment: he said: For each (shopID, productID) combination

Comment: Thanks @AndyL. . It does work @ ansev, just tested it again

Answer (score 0):

`sort_values` and `drop_duplicates` should work. As you title mentions `specific date`, I guess you also want to group `date`. If you don't, just take out `date` from `cols`

```
cols = ['Date', 'ShopID', 'ProductID']
df1 = df.sort_values(cols + ['Quantity']).drop_duplicates(cols, keep='last')    

Out[31]:
         Date  ShopID  ProductID  Quantity Desc
1  2019-10-01       1          1         3    b
5  2019-10-02       1          2         6    f
8  2019-10-03       2          1         6    i
```